# Problem with imported SVG - cannot convert curves to mesh properly

Tags: mesh, import, svg, conversion, splines

I imported an SVG caption from CorelDRAW and all letters are fine and get converted nicely to mesh, except the first one - "S". When I convert it to mesh it disappears. Also, it's the only spline that didn't get automatically filled. I think that the source file is fine but maybe there's some issue with "S" letter.
What can I do to fill my "S" and convert it to mesh like other letters? Is that spline not closed?

Here's the SVG...
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1ZUxZ9E8AJ6v85qh_iY70hMDUmeW5JvdT/view?usp=sharing

...and BLEND with imported caption:
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1krVFd9QTmQGibOeA7eRGVqJhFmjsXP45/view?usp=sharing

Sorry, I don't know how to post attachments here.

Comment: Ok, I updated the title.

Comment: I can't download you file because the site asks me to login. You might want to consider uploading it to the site used especially for Blender StackExchange: https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/ Also please try not to confuse a Comment with an Answer. : ) It is best if answers are soley used to give answers to a question.

Comment: Okay, I fixed the file access on google drive. Can you please look again? In the meantime I'll figure out the site you suggested.
Sure, I removed my non-answering answer :P

Comment: I added the BLEND file to Blend-Exchnage and put link to this thread but I don't know if it worked. But now you should be able to open files from my google drive.

Answer (score 0):

There is a hidden extra vertex in your curve object that confuses curve behavior.

The vertex is located on the left from the top right vertex in the S, marked with the green square in the picture. It is actually selected (and should look white) but because it is behind another vertex you can't see it.

Click on the location twice, so you won't see a white selection (but in the bottom right corner it still says: "Vert 1/414") Then press <kbd>X</kbd> or <kbd>Del</kbd> and choose Dissolve Vertices. This should resolve your issue.

[image]